# Here API - Need guidance defining query, q, value

Tags: here-api

The HERE api seems really picky about what is uses for the q parameter in API calls. According to the documentation you can use a street address, partial address, name of place, etc (documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/free-text-search.html)

Im trying to take an address and return the name of the store, building, business at that location (a few million of these) In some cases I have a human typed name of the place at the address but this can be quite messy and inaccurate in a lot of cases so Im trying not to use this information. Address however Im quite confident in.

in summary Im trying to provide here with an input like "15300 Cedar Ave, Apple Valley, MN 55124" and output "Best Buy"

Here seems to be really finicky on what your q input is..

When I put in the address and geocode info, Best Buy doesn’t appear on the results list

```
q=15300 Cedar Ave, Apple Valley, MN 55124
in=44.7287,-93.2147;r=800
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?q=15300+Cedar+Ave%2C+Apple+Valley%2C+MN+55124&in=44.7287%2C-93.2147%3Br%3D800&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```

Based on this Im thinking maybe this info just isnt in here's database, but when I run this query which includes best buy in the search it finds it right away at the correct address!!

```
q=best buy 15300 Cedar Ave, Apple Valley, MN 55124
in=44.7287,-93.2147;r=800
https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?q=best+buy+15300+Cedar+Ave%2C+Apple+Valley%2C+MN+55124&in=44.7287%2C-93.2147%3Br%3D800&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```

It seems like a no-brainer to me that HERE would use the q value as an address search but that doesnt always appear to be the case. Looking for guidance on how to make this smarter

Answer (score 0):

if the point of interest(POI) needs to be **searched** by specific address, then q is significant for fetching the records. As the API will fetch only those records which have those keywords in that area.

if POIs need to be searched at specific lat-long and around defined meter range, then q is not significant.

https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?in=44.7287%2C-93.2147%3Br%3D800&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Is it mandatory for you to pass address all the time, or lat-long can also work ?